# SQL Server Restore Error - Write on ??? failed

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-restore

I'm trying to restore a full backup (SQL Server 2008) from a network drive and I'm getting the error message:

*Msg 3202, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
Write on "???" failed: 1(Incorrect function.)*

*Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.*

I've tried twice with the most recent full backup, I then went to an older full backup, they all fail with the same message at around 90%

My first guess is that this is an issue with one of the drives it's restoring to, however chkdsk seems happy and I'm not getting any other related errors in the Event Logs or SQL Server.

Anyone have any suggestions of what to look into?

EDIT: command being used:

```
  restore database CustomerData
  from disk = '\\server\SQL Archive\CustomerData - 20170225.bak'
  with file = 1,
       move 'CustomerData_Data' to 'C:\MSSQL\Data\CustomerData_Data.mdf',
       move 'CustomerData_Index' to 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.VDI01P\MSSQL\DATA\CustomerData_Index.ndf',
       move 'CustomerData_Log' to 'D:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.VDI01P\MSSQL\DATA\CustomerData_Log.ldf',
       password = '',
       mediapassword = '',
       norecovery;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but do you have sufficient space left on the target drive ?

Also, this thread is potentially relevant to your situation: [SQL Server backup fails on disk space error](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/50487/sql-server-backup-fails-on-disk-space-error)

Comment: Thanks for the reply!

I'm running the restore command with "MOVE" parameters which are stating where to put the index/log/data files across 2 drives, as soon as I run the command it seems to create the files and allocate the space, there's still 40+ GB free on each drive...so as far as I can tell I'm not running out of space and there are no messages about such.

Comment: Seeing that you are restoring from network, one thing you that could try is copy the backup file to a local drive (provided that you have enough disk space available), and attempt to restore locally. Did you check the SQL server logs or the Windows event logs ?

Comment: Unfortunately there isn't enough space and yes, nothing in the logs other then the message I posted that shows up in both SQL server and Windows logs.

Comment: The backup file is probably compressed to some extent, so you might actually be running out of space. Keep an eye on available disk space while doing the restore to see what happens. I would maybe try restoring one file at a time (the move statement). Another possible workaround: restore the 3 files from backup to another location (network or otherwise) where there is ample space available, rather than your local drives.

Comment: I checked  the original backup command, it's not stating to use compression. I did watch the space while the restore ran, but it didn't change, I believe when you run the restore the first thing it does is create the database files and allocates the needed space for them, then starts filling up those files. I think restoring to another location is my only option, going to see if I can have someone plug in a USB drive or something of the like.